# How can I put the formula only in the last 20 rows of this range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want that this code works only in the last 20 rows of the sheet. Now It sets a formula in all of the blanks cells of a column but I want that this code do that only in the 20 last rows.

```
   function setFormulaInBlankCells()  {
//----------------- COLONNA A ---------------
// formula solo su celle vuote "Area"
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getMaxRows();
  var lastColumn=sheet.getMaxColumns();    
  var range=sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1);
  var data=range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
  if(!data[i][0])
  {
    var E1=sheet.getRange(i+1,5).getA1Notation();
    var I1=sheet.getRange(i+1,9).getA1Notation();
     var formula='=IFERROR(IF(' + E1 + '="";"";IF(' + I1 + '="";"RU";"ST")))'
     sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setFormula(formula); 
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Change the starting value of i to data.length-20;

Comment: "lastRow-20" or "lastRow-19"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant in the last 20 rows of the sheet

```
function setFormulaInBlankCells()  
{
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow=sheet.getMaxRows();   
  var range=sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1);
  var data=range.getValues();
  for(var i=data.length-20;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    if(!data[i][0])
    {
      var E1=sheet.getRange(i+1,5).getA1Notation();
      var I1=sheet.getRange(i+1,9).getA1Notation();
       var formula='=IFERROR(IF(' + E1 + '="";"";IF(' + I1 + '="";"RU";"ST")))'
       sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setFormula(formula); 
    }
  } 
}
```